# CSS - icon over text

Tags: html, css

I have this html to show my navigation:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav mainMenu">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-dashboard"></span><span class="menuText">Menu1</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span><span class="menuText">Menu2</span></a></li>
            ...
    </ul>           
</div>
```

My navigation looks like this:

[image: navigation]

Now I want to have the icon over the text but somehow it is not that simple that I thought.
Does someony have any idea how to do this in a simple way?

Answer (score 2):

Add `display:block` to your spans so that they wrap to new lines.

Ex:

```css
.glyphicon {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav mainMenu">
    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-dashboard">a</span><span class="menuText">Menu1</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home">b</span><span class="menuText">Menu2</span></a></li>
    ...
  </ul>
</div>
```

[Ref](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QMWpRo)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```css
.collapse {
   display: block !important;
}
.mainMenu li {
    display: inline-block !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav mainMenu">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-dashboard"></span><span class="menuText">Menu1</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span><span class="menuText">Menu2</span></a></li>
            ...
    </ul>           
</div>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-dashboard"></span><span class="menuText">Menu1</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span><span class="menuText">Menu2</span></a></li>
            ...
    </ul>           
</div>
```

Comment: @user3318489 if any doubt let me know